# how to decompress http response?

Tags: java

Can any one of you solve this problem !

Problem Description:

i have received content-encoding: gzip header from http web-server.
now i want to decode the content but when i use GZIP classes from jdk 1.6.12, it gives null.

does it means that contents are not in gzip format ? or are there some another classes for decompress http response content?

### Sample Code:

```
System.out.println("Reading InputStream");
InputStream in = httpuc.getInputStream();// httpuc is an object of httpurlconnection<br>
System.out.println("Before reading GZIP inputstream");
System.out.println(in);
GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in));
System.out.println("After reading GZIP inputstream");
```

### Output:

```
Reading InputStream
Before reading GZIP inputstream
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@8acf6e
null
```

I have found one error in code, but don't able to understand it properly. what does it indicates.

Error ! java.io.EOFException

Thanks

Comment: Are you decompressing the response body, as opposed to the complete stream ? It would be useful to see your code

Answer (score 4):

I think you should have a look at [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/), which will handle a lot of the HTTP issues for you. In particular, it allows access to the response **body**, which may be gzipped, and then you simply feed that through a GZIPInputStream

e.g.

```
    Header hce = postMethod.getResponseHeader("Content-Encoding");
    InputStream in = null;
    if(null != hce)
    {
     if(hce.getValue().equals(GZIP)) {
        in = new GZIPInputStream(postMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream());
     }
         // etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    InputStream bodyStream = new GZIPInputStream(is);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int length;
    while ((length = bodyStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    String body = new String(outStream.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

I second Brian's suggestion. Whenever u need to deal with getting/posting stuff via HTTP don't bother with low-level access use the Apache HTTP client.